# The difference between 87% and 71% of a number is 448. What is 59% of that number

Tags: arithmetic

Today I came across an objective type question in that I have to choose from 4 optiona. I found myself struggling with this question since I have not been in touch with Math since I completed my graduation.

The question was:

**The difference between 87% and 71% of a number is 448. What is 59% of that number?**

```
1562
1652
1662
1552
```

I would really appreciate any help on this.

Comment: $0.87x-0.71x=448$ and solve for $x$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a reasoning from elementary school:

The difference is $16\,\%$ of that number. So, $1\,\%$ is $16$ times less, i.e. $\frac{448}{16}=28$, and $59\,\%$ is $59$ times the latter:
$$59\times 28=1652.$$

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, $0.87x - 0.71x = 448$. Then you can use the [unitary method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unitary_method):

$$0.16x=448$$
$$0.01x=28$$
$$0.59x = \ ?$$

Answer (score -1):

Use the rule of three.

$448$ is for $16$
like $x$ is for 59

then:

$$\frac{59 \times 448}{16} = ?$$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).